# Assign a variable in EditText

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I have a project in android studio. I want to assign a  variable in EditText.And I want to print the screen on a condition when clicking on the button

```
final Button btn_baslat =(Button)findViewById(R.id.btn_onayla);
final TextView txt_yazi =(TextView)findViewById(R.id.txt_hazir);
final EditText editxt_deger =(EditText)findViewById(R.id.et_trojanyaz);
final String editxt_okuma = editxt_deger.getText().toString();

btn_baslat.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        if(editxt_okuma.equalsIgnoreCase("myalfa")){
            txt_yazi.setText("BAŞARDIN !");
        }
        else{
            txt_yazi.setText("BAŞARAMADIN !");
        }
    }
});
```

In this code when I write EditText "myalfa" it does not show "BAŞARDIN !"

Comment: What is the problem you can try solve?

Comment: Instead of an image of your code, paste the actual relevant code into your question.

Comment: I add actual relevant code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to compare the `EditText` value rather can comparing the actual `EditText` itself.
Try this inside `onClick` method,

```
btn_baslat.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        String text = editxt_deger.getText().toString();
        if(text.equalsIgnoreCase("myalfa")){
            txt_yazi.setText("BAŞARDIN !");
        } else {
            txt_yazi.setText("BAŞARAMADIN !");
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Thank you so much for answer.And its String text =editxt_deger.getText().toString();